# How do I set v-model to an object property when the object is loaded asynchronously in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, v-model

I'm work with a vue.js application and I want to set v-model on a checkbox input to a property of an object that is loaded asynchronously. Here's the code:

```
        <v-layout>
          <v-checkbox required v-model="notifications.email">
          </v-checkbox>
          <p>I would like to receive notifications by email.</p>   
        </v-layout>

        ...

        export default {
        ...
        data: () => ({
            ...
            notifications: null
            ...
        })
        ...
        async created() {
            this.notifications = await api.get('/notifications');
        }
        ...
        }
```

In other words, v-model is set to an undefined property at first (because the notifications object is null at first). After the created hook runs and the notifications object is returned from the call to the API, then the notifications object exists and has the property 'email'.

Because the notifications object is null at first, the browser throws an error saying "Cannot read property 'email' of null" and halts execution.

Is there a way to set v-model to something that is loaded asynchronously (or later in the lifecycle of the page)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply initialize the notifications with { email: null } instead of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computed property (@Anatoly, Upd. I have added getters and setters):

```
computed: {
    notifications_email: {
        get: function(){
            if(typeof this.notifications !== 'undefined'){
                return this.notifications.email;
            }    else{
                return false;
            }
        },
        set: function(val){
            this.notifications.email = val;
        }
    }

}
```

and replace your checkbox with:

```
<v-checkbox required v-model="notifications_email">
```

PS. But it looks for me overhead now.

Comment: In case of computed property in v-model you should define gettter and setter.